# heroku run rake db:migrate failed: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm a novie in heroku. When I was performing my CS169.1x homework2 (deploying an application) I ran into a problem with database filling using the following command: heroku run rake db:migrate. Here is terminal dump:

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/hw2_rottenpotatoes$ git pull heroku master
From heroku.com:afternoon-cove-7289
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/hw2_rottenpotatoes$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/hw2_rottenpotatoes$ heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:migrate: command not found
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/hw2_rottenpotatoes$
```

What may be wrong? If there is error dump on heroku to check?

Comment: This happened to me just now. Seemed as if rake was simply not installed on the heroku server - though it had been working earlier. All rake commands failed with command not found. Differed from a rake failure, because no "rake aborted!" message. Switched over to another heroku app in the same account and the same commands succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the heroku gem? If you have heroku in the gemfile, you may need to do

```
bundle exec heroku run...
```

Comment: No, I installed necessary application gems by runnining the command:   bundle install --without production

Comment: so do you have heroku installed? `gem install heroku` or add it to the Gemfile (not in the production section)

Answer (score -1):

just to make sure you have heroku installed, what happens when you run:

```
$heroku help
```

Comment: Usage: heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]

Primary help topics, type "heroku help TOPIC" for more details:

  auth      # authentication (login, logout)
  apps      # manage apps (create, destroy)
and so on...